# DocumentGroup is sometimes creating multiple views

Tags: swiftui

In my application, I'm creating an object and adding data to it with an .onAppear. I've noticed sometimes (1 in 4 to 6 times), my object is being created multiple times, and the .onAppear is not being called for each.

After much trial and error, I reduced the code to the following.

I added an init to the ContentView to print when it is being called and in the read for the TextDocument. Most of the time when I open a text file, there is one "Read data" and one "Create view". Every 3 to 6 times, there is one "Read data" and three "Create view. The size of the text file does not change the frequency of the error.

I tried the same experiment with a WindowView and never saw multiple "Create view" messages.

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

@main
struct OneMoreTimeApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: TextDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: TextDocument
    
    init(document: Binding<TextDocument>) {
        print("Create view")
        self._document = document
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            Text(document.data)
        }
    }
}

struct TextDocument: FileDocument {
    static var readableContentTypes : [UTType] {[.text]}
    var data: String

    init(text: String = "This is some text") {
        print("init data")
        self.data = text
    }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        print("read data")
        if let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents {
            self.data = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
        } else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
    }

    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        print("write data")
        let outData = Data(data.utf8)
        return FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: outData)
    }
}
```

I'm thinking this is an Apple bug, but want it to run it by here first incase I'm doing something wrong.

Test Case

1. Launch the application
2. Open a text file
3. Wait ten seconds
4. Verify that the create view message is only printed once
5. Close the text file
6. Repeat steps 1 through 5 ten time.

It usually fails within 5 try.

I can also reproduce the issue by skipping step 5 and repeating steps 2 through 4, but it takes long to reproduce, up to 30 times.

I reproduced the problem on an iPad Pro (12.9-inch) )3rd gen) running 16.2
I reproduced the problem on an iPhone 14 Pro Max running 16.2
I reproduced the problem on an iPhone 14 simulator

I built the app with a target of 16.1, 16.0, 15.6 and 14.7. All shows the same problem.

Running Xcode 14.2

---

Here is a less trivial version that creates an object, which gets created multiple times.

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

@main
struct OneMoreTimeApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: TextDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: TextDocument
    @State var myObject = MyObject()
    
    init(document: Binding<TextDocument>) {
        print("Create view")
        self._document = document
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            Text("\(myObject.text)")
            Text(document.data)
                .onAppear{
                    print("onAppear - myObject is \(myObject.text)")
                    myObject.text += " - onAppear"
                }
        }
    }
}

struct TextDocument: FileDocument {
    static var readableContentTypes : [UTType] {[.text]}
    var data: String

    init(text: String = "This is some text") {
        print("init data")
        self.data = text
    }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        print("read data")
        if let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents {
            self.data = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
        } else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
    }

    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        print("write data")
        let outData = Data(data.utf8)
        return FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: outData)
    }
}

class MyObject : ObservableObject {
    static var numberOfObjects = 0

    @Published var text = "none"

    init() {
        MyObject.numberOfObjects += 1
        text = "Object number \(MyObject.numberOfObjects)"
        print("created \(text)")
    }

    deinit {
        print("killed \(text)")
    }
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI is allowed to call `body` as many times as it wants. If it wants to call the `body` of `OneMoreTimeApp` three times, it's allowed to. It's not clear from your post (including from the code in it) why that's a problem.

Comment: The problem is that it is performing the init multiple times, so if I create a object that object is getting created multiple times.

Comment: Don't create objects in SwiftUI structs. If you really need a reference type you can use `@StateObject` but that is a last resort. Try `@State var myStruct = MyStruct()` instead and init it with what you need instead of using `onAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever work you're doing in `ContentView.init` that you don't want repeated, you should move into an `ObservableObject` and store in a `@StateObject`-wrapped property instead.

Comment: The only thing I'm doing is getting the screen width from a GeometryReader using .onChange(of: geomerty.size) . The problem is that when the extra view are being create, my objet keeps getting update. On the extra creations of the View, the sizes are wrong so I get the wrong width. This work fine for WindowGroups, but fails for DocumentGroups. I tried changing the State to StateObject. It stoped the creation of extra objects, put the root problem still occurs. I can add the even less trivial case if that helps.

Comment: If your problem specifically involves a `GeometryReader` then you should post code that demonstrates the problem with a `GeometryReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Rob pointed me down a path that led to this slightly more complicated code. In it I create three copies of the object, one as a @state, one a StateObject and one as a @ObservedObjects.

The code compiles and generally works with all three. In the case where the View is created multiple times all three act differently.

The @State gets destroyed and recreated, but behind the scenes the old data is copied into the new object.

The @StateObject does not get destroyed.

The @ObservableObject is destroyed and left in its initialized state (the old data does not get copied into it.)

I the failing case I get the following prints:

read data

created Object0 number 1

created Object2 number 2

Create view

created Object1 number 3

onAppear

onChange - size is (1366.0, 878.0)

created Object0 number 4

created Object2 number 5

Create view

killed Object2 number 2 - onAppear

created Object0 number 6

created Object2 number 7

Create view

killed Object0 number 4

killed Object2 number 5

On the screen it shows:

Hello World
object 0 1,366.000000 text: Object0 number 1 - onAppear

object 1 1,366.000000 text: Object1 number 3 - onAppear

object 2 1,366.000000 text: Object7 number 7

CGFloat 1,366.000000

---

So, I had a bug in my code, I was using @ObservedObject when I should have been using @StateObject.

However, it still seems strange that view is getting created extra times and data is being copied from the old one to the new one (@State vars).

What do you guys think? should I report this to Apple or figure since there is code that does the copying when it happens it must be right?

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

@main
struct OneMoreTimeApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: TextDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: TextDocument
    @State var myObject0 = MyObject(0)
    @StateObject var myObject1 = MyObject(1)
    @ObservedObject var myObject2 = MyObject(2) // does not work
    @State var theWidth : CGFloat = 0

    init(document: Binding<TextDocument>) {
        print("Create view")
        self._document = document
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                GeometryReader { geomerty in
                    VStack {
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(height: 50)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        Text("Hello World")
                        Text("object 0 \(myObject0.width)  text:\(myObject0.text)")
                        Text("object 1 \(myObject1.width)  text:\(myObject1.text)")
                        Text("object 2 \(myObject2.width)  text:\(myObject2.text)")
                        Text("CGFloat  \(theWidth)")
                        Text(document.data)
                            .onAppear{
                                print("onAppear")
                                myObject0.text += " - onAppear"
                                myObject1.text += " - onAppear"
                                myObject2.text += " - onAppear"
                            }
                            .onChange(of: geomerty.size) { size in
                                print("onChange - size is \(geomerty.size)")
                                myObject0.width = size.width
                                myObject1.width = size.width
                                myObject2.width = size.width
                                theWidth = size.width
                            }
                        Button("set to 42") {
                            myObject0.width = 42.0
                            myObject1.width = 42.0
                            myObject2.width = 42.0
                            theWidth = 42.0
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TextDocument: FileDocument {
    static var readableContentTypes : [UTType] {[.text]}
    var data: String

    init(text: String = "This is some text") {
        print("init data")
        self.data = text
    }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        print("read data")
        if let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents {
            self.data = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
        } else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
    }

    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        print("write data")
        let outData = Data(data.utf8)
        return FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: outData)
    }
}

class MyObject : ObservableObject {
    static var numberOfObjects = 0

    @Published var text = "none"
    @Published var width : CGFloat = 0.0

    init(_ i:Int) {
        MyObject.numberOfObjects += 1
        text = "Object\(i) number \(MyObject.numberOfObjects)"
        print("created \(text)")
    }

    deinit {
        print("killed \(text)")
    }
}
```